# Website forwarding - actions do not seem to work

Tags: domains, jquery, ajax, domain-forwarding

I have the following website up and running: www.posti.sh
The website is actually on www.myskoob.com/postish/, but I use domain forwarding so that when the user types in www.posti.sh it stays that way and does not change to www.myskoob.com/postish/.
You can try out the website. It is generally about posting something and uses jQuery ajax to let the user perform posting.

Here's the problem:

While visiting www.myskoob.com/postish/, that works fine - all ajax calls seem to work. However, when I go to www.posti.sh, it does not work - I cannot understand why.

There are two ways of forwarding - one is frame forwarding (which then works) and the other is URL-hiding, which is a much cleaner way because that way the URL actually changes with different pages that are opened.

Anybody knows a reason why URL-hiding does not work? Thank you!

Dennis

Comment: How exactly does 'url-hiding' work? As discussed when you raised a similar question a few days ago, the best solution is to map the domain properly - then none of this would be an issue.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles Thank you! What exactly does proper mapping mean?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles URL-hiding means that when you type in posti.sh it redirects you to myskoob.com/postish/, but the url won't change. Please note that this is not the same issue like a few days ago.

Comment: Do you own myskoob?

Comment: No, they are friends, but I do have access to server configuration.

Comment: Basically what I'm suggesting is you buy yourself some website hosting and host your domain there, none of these redirection schemes is helping your user experience or SEO.

Comment: Sure, I thought about that - I only wanted to test the site and not buy hosting for 1 year without really knowing whether people actually visit the site.

Comment: It's a bit of a chicken and egg scenario, you need good SEO to attract visitors, and people need to know your site address to link to posts. The solutions you have in place are damaging your ability to promote your site.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles You are right. Is there any host you can recommend that I can transfer the files and the domain to?

Comment: What currency are you buying in?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've asked a few questions about this both here and over at StackOverflow.

The simple truth is that hosting on a sub-directory of a friend's site, and framed forwarding isn't helping your user experience, SEO, or your users share individual links to your site content.

All up this is hurting your ability to promote the site and gain a following.

So, while I appreciate it's not a direct answer to your question I would recommend that you buy a hosting account and host the site properly under www.posti.sh.